# Levelshift distorts when freq is higher than 4kHz

Tags: arduino, level-shifting

I 'designed' this circuit to shift a level coming from an arduino to -5/+5v signal. It simulates well in EASYEDA.

I also built it on a breadboard with a symmetrical powersupply and signalgen giving me a sine signal of 5v (0 - 5v).

It all works well up until a 4kHz, but above this frequency the output becomes like a triangle (it obviously is distorted to a triangle.)
Taking the input back to a sine of eg. 3v makes it more of a sine again, but obviously the signal at output is also less than the wanted -5/+5v.

Why does the signal distort when its quicker than about 4kHz? I want it to be clean up to 16kHz.
Could someone shed some light on this for me please?

(the scope shows 2 and 10kHz sine, yellow is input, blue output)

[image: levelshift 0v/5v to -5v/+5v]

[image: scopepicture at 2 kHz and 10kHz]

UPDATE: replaced the LM358 with a TL072, works properly now.

Comment: It distorts in real-life on a bread-board or in simulation?

Comment: Often getting a triangle when you're expecting a sine would suggest checking for slew-rate limiting somewhere in the signal chain. What are you using as the input signal generator and how does its waveform look at 4 kHz?

Comment: You've got a slew rate problem somewhere. Are those op amps actually LM358, or are you using a different op amp in the breadboarded circuit? (that said, even a 741 has a better slew rate than that...) Breadboards also add significant capacitance all over the place, so it could be that too.

Comment: it distorts in real life. I'm using LM358. I'll try 741's. I'm using a proper signalgen which gives a clean 4kHz sine. I'm looking at my scope (siglent) and see the distortion getting worse at about 4kHz. I'll look into the 'slewrate'. Thanks already!!

Comment: Try a faster opamp. 741 is not a faster opamp.

Comment: You need to have a slew rate of at least \$2 \pi V_p F\$. For a 10 volt peak signal at 16kHz, that yields a required slew rate of just over 1v/\$ \mu\$s. The LM358 has a *typical* slew rate of 0.3V/\$ \mu\$s. Note that actual slew rate is often less than the typical rate.

Comment: Don't try a 741. I mentioned that as the example of the worst op amp I know of. The 358 isn't much better, but it *is* better than a 741.

Comment: Yep, experienced that :-) Dropped in a  741; no joy. Dropped in TL072; joy. (Clean as a whistle up to about 400kHz.) Thank you all for you help, much appreciated!!!

Comment: 2nd plot - blue seems to be leading the yellow, something's not right...

Comment: @grambo that is the signal delay through the amplifier.

Comment: @Hearth I guess you've never met a 709.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have not, and from context I would prefer not to, I think!

Comment: @user3810130: Congratulations on your fix. Please post it as an answer. You can then accept your own answer to mark it solved. (You may have to wait a day.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropped in a 741; no joy. Dropped in TL072; joy. (Clean as a whistle up to about 400kHz.) Thank you all for you help, much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Disagreeing with the prior comments...
You are way slower than where you should see speed related issue with the 358.  GBW is 1.2 MHz, you are running gain of 2 so you should be good to 600kHz small signal.  Slew rate 0.5V/us is also faster than you are if I'm reading the scope correctly.  What you have is more likely a phase margin issue.  I've sim'd this and your circuit is showing ~130° phase lag.  Swapping to the TL072 changes that to 90°.

I believe that LM358 should be fine in a diff amp configuration (ref changes to 2.5V to match the sig gen) with a little low pass filtering to avoid the phase margin issue:
[image]

Comment: The scope plot above is a classic slew rate limited waveform; the LM358 also has a *typical* slew rate of 0.3V/\$ \mu\$s

Comment: Wait, 8v/50us is half of the spec'd slew rate...

Comment: A particular device can easily be much worse than the typical specification.

Comment: @Hearth see edits, it's phase margin, not slew rate

Comment: @grambo I'm not sure where you're getting that from. This isn't a system in which phase margin should matter, as far as I'm aware, and it certainly wouldn't cause that kind of distortion.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet for the lousy old LM358 shows it has slew rate trouble above 2kHz and the lousy old 741 opamp (52 years old!) above 9kHz. They are both noisy and the LM358 also produces crossover distortion.